# How get values from database scadalts from last day

Tags: scadalts

I need to get data from DB scadalts from last day.

I have data in table pointValues where is column pointValue and ts but is not timestamp.

Column `ts` is type `BIGINT(20)`

Checking ts is unixtime

```
     SELECT 
        pointValue,
        ts, 
        from_unixtime(ts),
        YEAR(from_unixtime(ts)),
        MONTH(from_unixtime(ts)),
        DAY(from_unixtime(ts))
     FROM 
        pointValues;
```

The result `null` is wrong is not unixtime.

I don't know how to create condition `where` because - I don't know how to interpret value in column `ts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `ts` should be interpreted with greater accuracy.

eg:

```
SELECT 
    pointValue,
    ts, 
    from_unixtime(ts/1000),
    YEAR(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
    MONTH(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
    DAY(from_unixtime(ts/1000))
 FROM 
    pointValues;
```

And we may get values from last day eg:

```
SELECT 
    pointValue,
    ts, 
    YEAR(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
    MONTH(from_unixtime(ts/1000)),
    DAY(from_unixtime(ts/1000))
FROM 
    pointValues
WHERE
    YEAR(from_unixtime(ts/1000)) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 day) and
    MONTH(from_unixtime(ts/1000)) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 day) and
    DAY(from_unixtime(ts/1000)) = DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 day)
```

Thanks

Maybe it will be useful also